# how to split a datetime into weeks/months depending on what the user puts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, split

I am creating a report which will use a bar chart that will be split depending on what the user has inputted into the Start date and end date.

If the user put a start date and end date which is less then 8 weeks then the date will be split into weeks but if it is 8 weeks or more it is to be split into months.

e.g. if a user puts a date like 01/11/2013 - 30/11/2013 then it will be split into 01/11/2013 - 03/11/2013, 04/11/2013 - 10/11/2013, 11/11/2013 - 17/11/2013, 18/11/2013 - 24/11/2013, 25/11/2013 - 30/11/2013

but if the put a date like 01/05/2013 - 30/11/2013 it will split into 01/05/2013 - 31/05/2013, 01/06/2013 - 30/06/2013 and so on.

I have @StartDate and @EndDate for my parameters, I have looked around and tried a number of different things but cant get it to work any help would be great!

Thanks

Thomas James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go..

```
declare @startDate datetime='09/01/2013'
declare @endDate datetime='11/30/2013'
DECLARE @WEEKCOUNT INT
declare @magic int

SELECT @WEEKCOUNT = DATEDIFF(WEEK,@startDate,@endDate)
SELECT @magic = case when @WEEKCOUNT<8 then @WEEKCOUNT else (month(@endDate)-month(@startDate))+1 end


;WITH CTESplit
as
(
    select 1 as weekcount,
    CASE WHEN @WEEKCOUNT < 8 THEN DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @startDate))+1, @startDate) 
    ELSE DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(@startDate)-1), @startDate) END  [WeekStart], 
    CASE WHEN @WEEKCOUNT < 8 THEN DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @startDate))+1, @startDate) 
    else DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate)+1,0)) end [WeekEnd]


    union all

    select a.weekcount+1 as weekcount,
    CASE WHEN @WEEKCOUNT < 8 THEN DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @startDate+(7*(a.weekcount+1))))+2, @startDate+(7*(a.weekcount+1))) 
    ELSE DATEADD(dd, -(DAY(@startDate+(30*(a.weekcount+1)))-1), @startDate+(30*(a.weekcount+1))) END  [WeekStart], 
    CASE WHEN @WEEKCOUNT < 8 THEN DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, @startDate+(7*(a.weekcount+1))))+1, @startDate+(7*(a.weekcount+1))) 
    else DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@startDate+(30*(a.weekcount+1)))+1,0)) end [WeekEnd]
    from CTESplit a where (a.weekcount+1)<=@magic



)

select * from CTESplit
```

Comment: FYI - Feb 1, 2015 - Feb 28, 2015 Does not return correct data, only returns 3 weeks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're using SQL Server ?

Why not use the `week` parameter available already and make your life easier ?

```
group by datepart(week, YourDate)
```

This will give you the week number of the year. Either shift your date to the start of the next or previous week or have partials at either end of your groups.